# Задача. Общая стоимость товара

Tags: javascript

```
const products = [
  { name: "Radar", price: 1300, quantity: 4 },
  { name: "Scanner", price: 2700, quantity: 3 },
  { name: "Droid", price: 400, quantity: 7 },
  { name: "Grip", price: 1200, quantity: 9 },
];

function calculateTotalPrice(productName) {
const totalPrice = 0;
for (const product of products){
if(product[productName]){
totalPrice[productName] = product.price * product.quantity
}
console.log(totalPrice[productName] = product.price * product.quantity)
}
return totalPrice;
}

console.log(calculateTotalPrice('Radar'))
```

помогите понять как в totalPrice поместить общую сумму

Comment: первый лог вызывает результат(не могу понять как этот результат поместить в totalPrice)

Comment: у вас totalPrice - число, а вы пытаетесь добавить элемент в него как к объекту, естественно, что данные не сохранятся

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать функцию `.find` в JavaScript, для поиска необходимого вам продукта:

```js
const products = [
  { name: "Radar", price: 1300, quantity: 4 },
  { name: "Scanner", price: 2700, quantity: 3 },
  { name: "Droid", price: 400, quantity: 7 },
  { name: "Grip", price: 1200, quantity: 9 },
];
    
function calculateTotalPrice(productName) {
    const product = products.find(p => p.name == productName);
    return product.price * product.quantity;
};
    
console.log(calculateTotalPrice('Radar'))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const products = [
  { name: "Radar", price: 1300, quantity: 4 },
  { name: "Scanner", price: 2700, quantity: 3 },
  { name: "Droid", price: 400, quantity: 7 },
  { name: "Grip", price: 1200, quantity: 9 },
];

function calculateTotalPrice(productName) {
for(const product of products){
let totalPrice = product.price * product.quantity;
if(productName === product.name){
return totalPrice;
}
}
return 0;
}
```

вот ответ

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Чем вам не угодил ответ Артёма? Тем более ваш код будет работать дольше чем уже данный ответ. Вы каждый раз попусту считаете `totalPrice` пока не найдёте нужное название